# QgsFeatureRequest with expression on joined fields in pyqgis

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a shape layer in a QGIS 2.8 project with fields A and B joined to a Oracle database layer with field C.

I am writing a plugin to search the shape for fields A, B, and C.  I am doing this with a QgsFeatureRequest.  I get no results when the joined field C is in my Expression.  The Expression with the joined field does work fine if I put it in the ExpressionEditor in the Attribute Table.  The Expression without the joined field also gives me results in the code.

Is it not possible to do a QgsFeatureRequest using fields that are joined to the layer?

Here my code:

```
# GEM_NAME is the joined field from an Oracle Table
# FLUR and FLSTCK are present in the Shape file

expr = u"""upper(\"GEM_NAME\") like \'%{}%\'
           and \"FLUR\" = {}
           and \"FLSTCK\" = {}"""
layer = self.getLayerByName("flurstueck")
features = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(expr))
```